# Image of affine subspace is itself affine

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-writing, linear-transformations

> Let $A$ be an affine subspace of $V$ and $T \in \text{Hom}(V, W)$. The $T$-Image of $A$, $T[A]$, is an affine subspace of $W$.

I’m trying to prove this proposition. This is my progress:

Take any $T(\alpha) \in T[A]$. So $T(\alpha)=T(a + \epsilon)$ assuming $A=\{a+\epsilon:\epsilon \in V\}$. Then $T(\alpha)=T(a + \epsilon)=T(a) + T(\epsilon) \in \{T(a)+\epsilon:\epsilon \in W\}$.

To complete the proof, I need to show that $\{T(a)+\epsilon:\epsilon \in W\} \subset A$. I’m having trouble doing that since $T$ is not bijective.

Any hints are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be an affine subspace of $V$, i.e., $A = a + U$, where $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $a\in V$.

For each linear mapping $T:V\rightarrow W$, $T(A) = T(a) + T(U)$,
where $T(a)\in W$ and $T(U)$ is a subspace of $W$, since $T$ is linear.
Thus $T(A)$ is an affine subspace of $W$.

The linear mapping $T$ need not be bijective.